# How to implement partial refresh like facebook like/comments?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

We have java web application. Summary page will display list of rows. For each row, user can vote and add comments. Vote or add comments will commit immediately and refresh total vote number and comments count. We want to refresh current row instead of whole table just like Facebook does.  If need, we can show the list of data with form format (iterator List of data) instead of table format.  How to implement this feature base on JSF?

Answer (score 3):

you need write  server side script to update the votes  (JSP in your case I guess) 
and call it with AJAX through javascript function that will get back from the server (the response) the current number of votes - and replace the previous number in the DOM.

this has nothing to do with facebook (this is a good example - but the question is not on facebook api or something like that - so if you ask me it shouldn't be tagged under "facebook" tags)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF it is a good idea to look on frameworks like RichFaces, PrimeFaces and IceFaces. They all have rich ajax components. If not, you can do it by hands with AJAX.